# How can I align my adsense graphics?

Tags: html, css

I use google adsense and I added an image ad and it is not aligned. How can I align it? The CSS is available [here](http://pastebin.com/kxhQH0u6). I added an advertisement unit below my map and it renders somewhat too much to the left. What can be done about it?

. [image]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords"
          content="Houses Apartments, Vacation homes, Offices, Land, Flatmates,Paying Guest, Other real estate, Cars, Motorcycles, Accessories  parts, Trucks, Other vehicles, Home  Garden, Clothing, For Kids (Toys  Clothes), Jewelry  Watches, Hobbies, Sports  Bicycles, Movies, Books  Magazines, Pets, Tickets, Art  Collectibles, Music  Instruments, Computers  Accessories, TV, Audio, Video, Cameras, Cellphones  gadgets, Video games  consoles, Job offers, Resumes, Services, Classes, Professional,Office equipment, Other,  ">
    <meta name="description"
          content="Find jobs, cars, houses, mobile phones and properties for sale in your region conveniently. Find the best deal among {{count}} free ads online!">

    <title>Free classifieds in India - Koolbusiness.com</title>

    <link href="/static/css/koolindex_in.css?0.238133053892" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?0.238133053892"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% include "kooltopbar.html" %}

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>


        function drawMap() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Province'],
        ['Goa'],
        ['Gujarat'],

         ['Andhra Pradesh'],
['Arunachal Pradesh'],
['Assam'],
['Bihar'],
['Chhattisgarh'],
['Goa'],
['Gujarat'],
['Haryana'],
['Himachal Pradesh'],
['Jammu and Kashmir'],
['Jharkhand'],
['Karnataka'],
['Kerala'],
['Madhya Pradesh'],
['Maharashtra'],
['Manipur'],
['Meghalaya'],
['Mizoram'],
['Nagaland'],
['Orissa'],
['Punjab'],
['Rajasthan'],
['Sikkim'],
['Tamil Nadu'],
['Tripura'],
['Uttaranchal'],
['Uttar Pradesh'],
['West Bengal'],
['Delhi'],
['Lakshadweep'],
['Daman and Diu'],
['Dadra and Nagar Haveli'],
['Chandigarh'],
['Pondicherry'],
['Andaman and Nicobar Islands']
    ]);

 var options = {
           region:'IN',
          backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
          datalessRegionColor: '#ffc801',
      width:468,
       height:278,
     resolution: 'provinces',
        };
    var container = document.getElementById('mapcontainer');
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);

    function myClickHandler(){
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        var message = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
            var item = selection[i];
           // if (item.row != null && item.column != null) {
                message += '{row:' + item.row + ',column:' + item.column + '}';
            //} else
             if (item.row != null) {
                message += '{row:' + item.row + '}';
            //} else if (item.column != null) {
              //  message += '{column:' + item.column + '}';
            }
        }
        if (message == '') {
            message = 'nothing';
        }
        //alert('You selected ' + message);

        if (item.row==2) {
             window.location = "/andhra_pradesh/";
        }
        if (item.row==3) {
             window.location = "/arunachal_pradesh/";
        }
        if (item.row==4) {
             window.location = "/assam/";
        }
        if (item.row==6) {
             window.location = "/chhattisgarh/";
        }
        if (item.row==8) {
             window.location = "/gujarat/";
        }
        if (item.row==9) {
             window.location = "/haryana/";
        }
        if (item.row==10) {
             window.location = "/himachal_pradesh/";
        }
        if (item.row==11) {
             window.location = "/jammu_kashmir/";
        }
        if (item.row==12) {
             window.location = "/jharkhand/";
        }
        if (item.row==14) {
             window.location = "/kerala/";
        }
        if (item.row==15) {
             window.location = "/madhya_pradesh/";
        }
        if (item.row==16) {
             window.location = "/maharashtra/";
        }
        if (item.row==17) {
             window.location = "/manipur/";
        }
        if (item.row==18) {
             window.location = "/meghalaya/";
        }
        if (item.row==19) {
             window.location = "/mizoram/";
        }
        if (item.row==20) {
             window.location = "/nagaland/";
        }
        if (item.row==21) {
             window.location = "/orissa/";
        }
        if (item.row==22) {
             window.location = "/punjab/";
        }
        if (item.row==23) {
             window.location = "/rajasthan/";
        }
        if (item.row==24) {
             window.location = "/sikkim/";
        }
        if (item.row==25) {
             window.location = "/tamil_nadu/";
        }
        if (item.row==28) {
             window.location = "/uttar_pradesh/";
        }
        if (item.row==29) {
             window.location = "/west_bengal/";
        }
        if (item.row==36) {
             window.location = "/andaman_nicobar_islands/";
        }
    }

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', myClickHandler);

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geochart'], callback: drawMap});






     </script>

<div id="wrapper">

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<div class="alert-outer alert-error">
    <a href="#" class="alert-closer" title="close this alert" onclick="removeIeNotification(this); return false;">×</a>

    <div class="alert-inner">
        <span><strong>You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer.</strong> For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade today!</span>

    </div>
</div>
![endif]-->
<header>


    <h1 id="logo" class="sprite_index_in_in_en_logo spritetext">koolbusiness.com - The right choice for buying &amp;
        selling in india</h1>

    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- v2 -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:15px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-7211665888260307"
         data-ad-slot="9119838994"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</header>

<![endif]-->

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- v2 -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:15px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-7211665888260307"
         data-ad-slot="9119838994"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
<div class="main">
<div class="column_left">
    <div class="box">

        <ul>
            <li>KoolBusiness is easy, free, and kool.</li>
            <li>Buy and sell <a href="/india/cars-for_sale">cars</a>, check our <a href="/india/real_estate">real
                estate</a>
                section, find <a href="/india/jobs">jobs</a>, and much more.
            </li>
            <li>Check our <strong><a href="/india">{{count}} ads online</a></strong> and find what you are looking for
                in
                your region or in all India.
            </li>
        </ul>


    </div>

    <div id="regions">


        <div class="region_links_one">
            <ul class="regions_one">
                <li><a id="region_8" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/andhra_pradesh/">Andhra
                    Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_9" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/arunachal_pradesh/">Arunachal
                    Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_10" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/assam/">Assam</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_11" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/bihar/">Bihar</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_12" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/chhattisgarh/">Chhattisgarh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_13" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/goa/">Goa</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_14" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/gujarat/">Gujarat</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_15" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/haryana/">Haryana</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_16" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/himachal_pradesh/">Himachal
                    Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_17" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/jammu_kashmir/">Jammu
                    &amp;
                    Kashmir</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_18" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/jharkhand/">Jharkhand</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_19" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/karnataka/">Karnataka</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_20" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/kerala/">Kerala</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_21" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/madhya_pradesh/">Madhya
                    Pradesh</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="regions_two">
                <li><a id="region_22" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/maharashtra/">Maharashtra</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_23" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/manipur/">Manipur</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_24" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/meghalaya/">Meghalaya</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_25" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/mizoram/">Mizoram</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_26" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/nagaland/">Nagaland</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_27" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/orissa/">Orissa</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_28" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/punjab/">Punjab</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_29" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/rajasthan/">Rajasthan</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_30" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/sikkim/">Sikkim</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_31" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/tamil_nadu/">Tamil
                    Nadu</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_32" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/tripura/">Tripura</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_34" class="region"
                       href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/uttaranchal/">Uttaranchal</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_33" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/uttar_pradesh/">Uttar
                    Pradesh</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_35" class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/west_bengal/">West
                    Bengal</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="region_links_two">
            <!-- ads here -->
            <h2>Union territories</h2>


            <ul class="regions_one">
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/delhi/">Delhi</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/lakshadweep/">Lakshadweep</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/daman_diu/">Daman &amp; Diu</a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/dadra_nagar_haveli/">Dadra &amp; Nagar
                    Haveli</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="regions_two">
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/chandigarh/">Chandigarh</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/pondicherry/">Pondicherry</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/andaman_nicobar_islands/">Andaman &amp;
                    Nicobar
                    Islands</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="my_wrapper">

<div id="mapcontainer">

     <div id='visualization'></div>

</div>
<div id="gads" style="clear:both">

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- frontpagebelowmap -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7211665888260307"
     data-ad-slot="3839303791"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>



</div>
</div>



<footer class="nohistory columns">



    <p class="first">A good deal is just around the corner!</p>


    <p>KoolBusiness is the right choice for safe buying and selling in India: a free classifieds website where you
        can buy and sell almost everything.</p>


    <p><a href="/ai">Post an ad for free</a> or browse through our categories. You will find thousands of free
        classifieds for cars, houses, mobile phones and gadgets, computers, pets and dozens of items and services in
        your state or union territory.</p>


    <p>

        <strong>KoolBusiness does not charge any fee and does not require registration.</strong> Every
        ad is checked so we can give you the highest quality possible for the ads on our site. That’s why
        KoolBusiness is the most convenient, easiest to use and most complete free ads site in India.</p>


    <div id="world_sites">





    </div>




</footer>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- frontpagebelowmap -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-7211665888260307"
 data-ad-slot="3839303791"></ins>
<script>
```

Try adding margin: auto to style and let me know how it works:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- frontpagebelowmap -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px; margin: auto"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-7211665888260307"
 data-ad-slot="3839303791"></ins>
<script>
```